# How to do refund in Braintree MarketPlace from submerchant account?

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have to make a refund from braintree marketplace with submerchant account, but it seems only two ways to refund i.e.,from master merchant account or both(submerchant and master merchant) account. Is it possible make refund with only submerchant account?

Answer (score 2):

Based on BT docs;

If the funds are not in escrow, you can issue a full or partial refund. The amount will be deducted from your master merchant bank account, not your sub-merchant’s funding source. BT has provided examples of ways to recoup these credits;

- Increase your service fees to mitigate losses due to high refund or chargeback rates from sub-merchants.
- Build logic in your integration that increases a sub-merchant’s service fees until any refund or chargeback balance is paid off.
- Collect payment information from your sub-merchants and store it in your Vault. When your master merchant bank account is debited for a refund or chargeback, you can charge your sub-merchant’s payment method. Keep in mind that standard Braintree transaction fees will apply.

https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/processing